# firefox 25 does not have play() defined for audio tags?

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, audio

I have the following audio tag:

```
<audio preload>
  <source src='/sounds/notify.ogg' type='audio/ogg'>
</audio>
```

I want to play it through js, so naturally I would expect calling $("audio").play() to do it (it's the only audio tag on the page), but I get an error stating play isn't defined. Upon inspecting it that is the case. The audio element has no play property. Every tutorial or resource I read says this is all you need to do, but... well, I just can't do it. Is my version of FF just broken or am I somehow missing something not stated in these various texts?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`play()` is a DOM method, not a jQuery method, which means that you'll need to get the actual DOM element before being able to get the `play` property. To get the actual DOM element, you can use the jQuery [`get()`](http://api.jquery.com/get) method:

```
$('audio').get(/*insert element index*/).play();
```

or simply use array indices:

```
$('audio')[/*insert element index*/].play();
```

And for even more choice, you can do something like this:

```
$('audio').eq(/*insert element index*/).prop('play')();
```

You could even do something like this to play each audio element:

```
$('audio').each(function () { this.play(); });
```

Comment: Thanks, I was under the impression that if there was only one element returned by the selection you didn't need to specify an index. It seemed to be working fine so far, but like I said below I'm probably misunderstanding some aspect of it.

Comment: @kryptobs2000: the jQuery object is a wrapper for the actual DOM element - although it does have its own functions and properties which look very similar and can have the same name as their DOM equivalents.

Answer (score 2):

As Qantas mentioned play is not a jQuery method, but you can easily add it if desired as below:

```
$.fn.play = function() {
   return this.each(function() {
      this.play();
   });
}
```

Comment: Ah, that explains it. I knew it wasn't a jquery method, but I thought you'd also be able to use methods attached to the returned element. I guess I just hadn't run into the situation yet at this point or either I'm still misunderstanding something. Inspecting the returned object in the developer console it had all kinds of properties I'd expect of the audio tag, just no play.